# Oil Collects in Skyward Hole below Engine

Tags: honda, accord, oil-leak, hole

My vehicle is 1999 Honda Accord EX 3.0L FI SOHC VTEC 6cyl

There is a skyward hole (see picture) where engine oil collects and is seen nearby (presumably by spilling over). The hole is beneath the engine, on where (I think, but could be wrong) the upper side of the oil pan is: right beneath the red arrow in the picture. The hole is a perfect circle and definitely not caused by some random event/rock or something.

1. What's this hole for?  Does it have a name?
2. Why would engine oil collect there?  That doesn't seem normal at all.
3. How might I go about fixing this "oil leak" problem?

Thank you very much.

[image: Right beneath red arrow]

[image: Right beneath red arrow]